# Calling process_data_events within a handler in pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Is the following kind of code supported in pika? I get the connection object within a handler, create a new channel, and do some message processing by calling `process_data_events` on the connection. So, the call to `process_data_events` that led to the handler being called has not returned when all this happens.

```
def handler(channel, method, props, msg):

    connection = channel.connection
    channel2 = connection.channel()
    channel2.basic_consume(queue2, handler2)
    channel2.basic_publish(exchange, routing_key, message)

    while some_condition:
        connection.process_data_events()

channel.basic_consume(queue1, handler)
channel.start_consuming()
```

It appears to work, but I want to make sure that there aren't any silent issues caused by the recursive call to `process_data_events`.

Comment: Why are you calling `process_data_events` within your handler? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is how I do things like async rpc's with pika
https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py#L80

Comment: @LukeBakken I want to make an rpc based on the contents of the incoming message

Comment: I suggest not using `BlockingConnection`. Please see the async examples [here](https://github.com/pika/pika/tree/0.12.0/examples).

Comment: Luke Bakken, are you aware that the public-facing tutorial for how to perform RabbitMQ RPC, on the RabbitMQ website, (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) specifically advises people to use process_data_events to accomplish this?