# How to implement synchronous producer call in RabbitMQ

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, locking, message-queue

I am currently looking to develop a **synchronous** workflow in a RabbitMQ producer-consumer setup. The producer will publish a message to the queue and it will take about 6 - 8 seconds for the consumer to finish processing and return the result to consumer. The producer will then get the result and continue to execute the rest of the code, *which requires the result from the consumer*.

I understand Message Queues are designed to be synchronous, but is there any method to implement the process `producer call -> consumer process -> consumer return result to producer` synchronous? I searched around and found [the tutorial from RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html), where it used a busy loop to do the waiting on the producer side:

`rpc_client.py` (producer)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import uuid

class FibonacciRpcClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        result = self.channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue

        self.channel.basic_consume(
            queue=self.callback_queue,
            on_message_callback=self.on_response,
            auto_ack=True)

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body

    def call(self, n):
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key='rpc_queue',
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                reply_to=self.callback_queue,
                correlation_id=self.corr_id,
            ),
            body=str(n))
        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.process_data_events()
        return int(self.response)

fibonacci_rpc = FibonacciRpcClient()

print(" [x] Requesting fib(30)")
response = fibonacci_rpc.call(30)
print(" [.] Got %r" % response)
```

`rpc_server.py` (consumer)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_queue')

def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    n = int(body)

    print(" [.] fib(%s)" % n)
    response = fib(n)

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id = \
                                                         props.correlation_id),
                     body=str(response))
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue='rpc_queue', on_message_callback=on_request)

print(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests")
channel.start_consuming()
```

But I do not think the busy loop `while self.response is None:` is a very good idea, since it adds a very heavy load to the server running this code. I tried to use a lock to acquire the lock on the producer side and send the lock object to the consumer side, so the consumer can release the lock when the processing is done and the lock is released. However, the RabbitMQ client for Python, [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), does not allow passing lock objects across the queue.

What will be an elegant way to avoid busy-wait to achieve the synchronous workflow here?

Comment: Seems like a python question, not so much a rabbitmq question. For example, this same implementation in node.js could be wrapped with a promise and then consumed without any loop.

Comment: I don't think this is producer/consumer. This looks more like RPC through message queues (hence the "client/server"), which as mentioned in RabbitMQ's own doc from your link is not advised. Also, as @joniba said, your question is more generally "how to asynchronously call a potentially long-running function and wait for the result". A good place to start would be [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), or maybe the links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54383679/2983568).

Answer (score 1):

The consumer should publish the result *elsewhere*, and the producer can wait for the result to be available. Note that publishing the results in a AMQP message broker is generally a bad idea.

That's the design from *result backends* in Celery, so I'd suggest you just do something very similar, if not install Celery right away and drop the manual usage of Pika.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#result-backends

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is the correct way to do what you want to do. If you have a problem with the `while` loop i suggest looking into something like `asyncio`'s event loop. You could create a future for the response and only resolve that future when the response comes back on the callback queue. But at the end of the day its the same thing. The event loop is a fancy while True loop.

I also caution against doing something like this. Fair warning, there are many things to consider if you're building a proper system...